# Does MW3 let more than one person play over LAN with one copy of the disc?

Tags: steam, pc, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I want to play over LAN with my family and friends without needing to buy more than one copy of the disc to play. This will be for the PC version as it will be on various PC's in the same house. Please let me know if it's possible, and if so, how it works, because they are using steam again...

Answer (score 3):

You can't log on with the same Steam account twice and you need Steam to play.  The only legal way is to buy a copy for everyone who wants to play.